# Persistent notifications in Unity

Tags: unity, 12.10

I'm a new user having just installed Ubuntu 12.10. I'm getting along well, but something is bugging me. I keep missing notifications which is getting me in trouble. Is there a way to make notifications / events more persistent? In Windows, for example, the taskbar flashes until I click it. In Android an icon stays in the taskbar until I tap or swipe it away. Regardless of the app.

Is there something similar I can do with Unity? Make the app icon flash when something happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I read an article about this quite a while ago, so I don't know if it's working at this moment.
The package is called "Recent Notifications" and can be found at: https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications

The original article where I read about it:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-never-miss-an-ubuntu-notification-again

How to install via the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications
```

Remember to log out and log back in.

Comment: Just tested on 12.10 - works and it is awesome. But a log out is required (edited the answer). And a clarification for anyone else confused: `recent-notifications` in the PPA is the package for gnome-panel (Classic Gnome), so for Unity, the instructions in the answer are correct. The Unity version will show only five notifications, if there are more notifications, it will eventually show them all once you delete newer ones.